# How to reply vs. what to reply

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

Example:

> "I'll ask you some questions. Don't worry if you don't know
> **what/how** to reply.

Are both options correct? Or only one?

Comment: _I don't know what to reply_ (what words to use). _I don't know how to reply_ (the question is so strange that I don't know how to formulate a sensible answer).

Comment: @KateBunting He replied curtly. That's how.

Comment: @Lambie - Yes, I read your answer - but I consider that my version is one way to interpret _you don't know how to reply_.

Comment: @KateBunting Sure, but that is something else, isn't it? I just don't see any problem with either one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"how"
How did she reply? [adverb]

- Briefly? Long-windedly? Not at all. Nicely? Politely? By emai? By snail mail?

"what"
What did she reply? [contents of the reply or object]

- "No, I won't. Yes, he will. Maybe, I don't know. The whole nine yards.

Answer (score 1):

"What to reply" sounds odd to me. Even the word "reply" is too formal. I would say it like this:

Don't worry if you don't know the answer.

Or an unnecessarily long sentence such as:

Don't worry if you don't know what to say in answer to the questions.

Saying the following sentence:

Don't worry if you don't know how to answer.

sounds odd. As if the person in question doesn't know how he is supposed to answer the question, orally, in written form, etc.

Comment: "I don't know what to reply" implies content. What one says.